# webpack, eslint : Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'

Tags: angularjs, gulp, webpack, eslint

In windows, I generated a webpack + angular.js application using fountain.js and in the webpack configuration file `eslint` is used as a preloader for javascript files:

```
preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint'
      }
    ],
```

but i got some errors as shown in the following console log :

```
$ gulp
[13:21:38] Starting 'default'...
[13:21:38] Starting 'clean'...
[13:21:39] Finished 'clean' after 11 ms
[13:21:39] Starting 'build'...
[13:21:39] Starting 'partials'...
[13:21:39] Finished 'partials' after 38 ms
[13:21:39] Starting 'other'...
[13:21:39] Starting 'webpack:dist'...
[13:21:39] Finished 'other' after 96 ms
[13:21:45] Time: 6661ms
                         Asset       Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
vendor-aefef07e2fb51ce95272.js     170 kB       0       vendor
  main-aefef07e2fb51ce95272.js  167 bytes       1       main

ERROR in ./src/scripts/app.js

M:\Learning Angular.js\Ultimate AngularJS Build a Real-World App from Scratch\fj
s_ngClassfieds_app\src\scripts\app.js
  1:31  error  Trailing spaces not allowed                      no-trailing-spac
es
  1:32  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'  linebreak-style
  2:2   error  Newline required at end of file but not found    eol-last
  2:7   error  'ngModule' is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
  2:54  error  Trailing spaces not allowed                      no-trailing-spac
es

? 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset    Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  547 kB       0
[13:21:45] Finished 'webpack:dist' after 6.73 s
[13:21:45] Finished 'build' after 6.77 s
[13:21:45] Finished 'default' after 6.79 s
```

and as these errors occur, the gulp/webpack tasks serie fail and no file will be generated as expected. When i comment the lines for eslint webpack preloader i get no problems and the application is generated and it's served.

I have tried to add `\r\n` as explained in [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style) but i still get these errors and there is no .eslintrc file associated with webpack in order to set any specific parameters in it to avoid this problem to happen.

Comment: Eslint is checkstyle. You can turn it off. If there is no .eslintrc file you can always add one. What's the problem? You dont want to change style or what?

Comment: Also look [here](https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader#options).

Comment: you can use `gulp-eol` to fix end of line character across all the files